# evaluateJavaScript() only works once

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, pyside, qwebview

I have the following code:
HTML + JavaScript

```
<style type="text/css">
.color1{
color: #3D8BD0;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mensagem">Mensage</div>
<script>
   $("#mensagem").click(function( event ) {
        printer.text('Hello');
   });
</script>
</body>
```

And the .py file:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import Slot, QObject, QUrl
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView
from threading import Timer

class Dac(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dac, self).__init__(parent)
        self.defultMsg = "default"
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.view = QWebView()
        self.view.resize(445, 791)
        self.view.load(QUrl("./page.html"))
        self.frame = self.view.page().mainFrame()
        self.frame.addToJavaScriptWindowObject('printer', self)
        self.view.show()
        self.app.exec_()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def changeText(self, mensagem):
        print mensagem
        self.frame.evaluateJavaScript(mensagem)

    @Slot(str)
    def text(self, message):
        print message
        strm = '$("#mensagem").html("'+message+'").addClass("color1");'
        self.changeText(strm) #this change the text
        t = Timer(6.5, self.timeoff)
        t.start()

    def timeoff(self):
        strm = '$("#mensagem").html("'+self.defultMsg+'").removeClass("color1");'
        self.changeText(strm) #this don't change
        print "debug"

dac = Dac()
```

When I run the Python file, the window opens and shows me the HTML page, then when I click in the div "mensagem" the text just changes one time.
So I think my problem is that the statement `self.frame.evaluateJavaScript(mensagem)` only works on the first time.

Is there anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, need to push up

Comment: I've tested your code with PyQt4 and the program crashes. Does this also happen when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

The callback you provide to `threading.Timer` will not be executed by the main thread. Since `QWebView` inherits from `QWidget`, you have to interact with it [from the main thread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html):

> Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread.

You can fix this by using `PySide.QtCore.QTimer` and replacing this code:

```
t = Timer(6.5, self.timeoff)
t.start()
```

With:

```
QTimer.singleShot(6.5 * 1000, self.timeoff)
```

`QTimer` works with Qt's event loop and therefore stays in the same thread.